# Sql sum() function based on input table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write sql query to below student marks table from which we need to calculate aggregate of marks for each student grade.

Below are rules/conditions to get the desired output:

1. If "A" student grade is present then don't consider the "B" grade.
   and do the aggregation. don't populate the B grade in the output table.
2. If "A" student are absent in the given table then check for "B" grade students and do the aggregation.

I tried something and to not getting the desired output. But still I have confusion to choose right approach to get desired output of this.

For Example: Here is my table and the desired query.

```
select exam,
   sum(CASE WHEN students_grade in ("A") THEN marks
       ELSE 
       students_grade in ("B") THEN marks END) aggregate
from input_table 
group by exam
```

input_table:

```
student_grade     Exam       Marks 
------------------------------------------------------
A                 test_1        10.00
B                 test_1        10.00
A                 test_1        10.00
A                 test_1        20.00
A                 test_1        20.00
B                 test_1        30.50
```

Desired Output:

```
student_grade     Exam       aggregate 
---------------------------------------------------------
A                 test_1        60.00
```

Please correct the above query to get desired output/to apply above conditions,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.students_grade, i.exam, sum(i.marks) as aggregate
from input_table i
inner join
(select exam, min(students_grade) as mng
from input_table
group by exam) t
on t.exam = i.exam and t.mng = i.students_grade
group by i.students_grade, i.exam
```

Assuming you are looking for the best grade (ordered by `min`) in each exam, the above query should work.

Comment: I think you mean for an inner join. A left join will screw up the output a little.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_grade, exam, sum(marks) AS aggregate
FROM input_table
GROUP BY student_grade, exam
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    left(MixCode, 1) as student_grade,
    exam,
    sum(
        case
            when MixCode in ('AA', 'BB') then marks
            when MixCode = 'AB' and student_grade = 'A' then marks
        end
    ) as aggregate
from
    input as i inner join
    (
        select exam, min(student_grade) + max(student_grade) as MixCode
        from input
        group by exam
    ) as m
        on m.exam = i.exam
group by exam
```

The query above might work best if you have other grade combinations to consider. I think the query below would also work. The idea here is really to say that you only want the highest tier of scores for each exam and ignore all others:

```
select min(student_grade) as student_grade, exam, sum(marks)
from input as i
where student_grade = (select min(student_grade) from input as i2 where i2.exam = i.exam)
group by exam
```

*Remember `min()` means a higher grade.

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_grade, Exam, Sum(Marks) aggregate from Table_1 where
   student_grade = isNull((select distinct student_grade from Table_1 where
       student_grade = 'A'), (select distinct student_grade from Table_1 where
          student_grade = 'B'))
group by student_grade, Exam
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when Amarks>0 then Amarks else Bmarks end)  as aggregate,exam
from(
   SELECT sum( case when student_grade='A' then marks else 0 end )as Amarks
   , sum( case when student_grade='B' then marks else 0 end )as Bmarks
   ,exam
FROM input_table
GROUP BY  exam
) a
```